# UIAlertView crashes when hit on OK buttons

Tags: ios, uialertview

My Application gets crashed when I hit on `OK` button. I do a network interaction and whenever there is a timeout, I throw this alert message.

It works fine on iOS6 devices. I see this issue only on iOS7 devices.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if (self.urlConnection == connection) {

        [self stopBlocking];

        NSString *msg = @"Cannot connect to server. Please verify that you have a VPN connection.";
        NSString *title = @"Connection Error";

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:msg
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
        [ServerListener shouldRunSyncMethodTimer:YES];
    }
}
```

**No error on the console logs. No crash logs generated.**

Comment: Where does it crash? What is the error?

Comment: Did you implemented `clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method of `UIAlertView`?

Comment: If it crashes then use the debugger and figure out where and why.

Comment: @ Akhilrajtr: No, I don't have clickedButtonAtIndex

Comment: @Maddy: It goes to UIApplication main method after it crashes and nothing displayed on the console logs. If I can figure out the problem myself, why I need to post it on forums? I am looking for a some help

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @RameshSangili If you can't tell us anything about the crash then there is no way anyone can help you. You have to do some research first so you can provide enough detail for people to help you.

Comment: @RameshSangili if you are not implementing any UIAlertView delegate methods, then set `delegate:nil` in alertView initialisation.

Comment: this is not related to `UIAlertView` , check your          `[ServerListener shouldRunSyncMethodTimer:YES];` method. Try commenting that line and running once. Probably the issue is with that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the delegate set it to `nil` in the initialization